# Show that { xy ∣ |x| = |y|, x ≠ y } is context-free

Tags: formal-languages, context-free

I remember coming across the following question about a language that supposedly is context-free, but I was unable to find a proof of the fact. Have I perhaps misremembered the question?

Anyway, here's the question:

> Show that the language $L = \{xy \mid |x| = |y|, x\neq y\}$ is context free.

Comment: Oh, that's a good one! <3

Comment: https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/151382/755

Answer (score 46, accepted):

**Claim**: $L$ is context-free.

**Proof Idea**: There has to be at least one difference between the first and second half; we give a grammar that makes sure to generate one and leaves the rest arbitrary.

**Proof**: For sake of simplicity, assume a binary alphabet $\Sigma = \{a,b\}$. The proof readily extends to other sizes. Consider the grammar $G$:

$\qquad\begin{align} 
  S &\to AB \mid BA \\
  A &\to a \mid aAa \mid aAb \mid bAa \mid bAb \\
  B &\to b \mid aBa \mid aBb \mid bBa \mid bBb 
\end{align}$

It is quite clear that it generates

$\qquad \mathcal{L}(G) = \{ \underbrace{w_1}_k x \underbrace{w_2v_1}_{k+l}y\underbrace{v_2}_l \mid |w_1|=|w_2|=k, |v_1|=|v_2|=l, x\neq y \} \subseteq \Sigma^*;$

the suspicious may perform a nested induction over $k$ and $l$ with case distinction over pairs $(x,y)$.

The length of a word in $\mathcal{L}(G)$ is $2(k+l+1)$. The letters $x$ and $y$ occur on positions $k+1$ and $2k+l+2$, respectively. When we split the word in half, i.e. after $(k+l+1)$ letters, then the first half contains the letter $x$ on position $k+1$ and the second half has the letter $y$ on position $k+1$.

Therefore, $x$ and $y$ have the same position (in their respective half), which implies $\mathcal{L}(G) = L$ because $G$ imposes no other restrictions on its language.

---

The interested reader may enjoy two follow-up problems:

**Exercise 1**: Come up with a PDA for $L$!

**Exercise 2**: What about $\{xyz \mid |x|=|y|=|z|, x\neq y \lor y \neq z \lor x \neq z\}$?

Comment: If we use this grammar, we can generate a string like: $ S \rightarrow AB $ $ A \rightarrow a $ $ B \rightarrow bBa, then B \rightarrow b $ After that, we got a S as abba! This is not equal to the raw language L, is there a mistake here?

Comment: @George.Zhao I don't follow. Cleary, $abba \in L$ with $x = ab$ and $y=ba$?

Comment: S->BA, B->aSb->abb, A->a, S->abba.