# Construct a PDA for the complement of $a^nb^nc^n$

Tags: formal-languages, automata, context-free, pushdown-automata

I am wondering if this is even possible, since $\{a^n b^n c^n  \mid n \geq 0\} \not\in \mathrm{CFL}$. Therefore a PDA that can distinguish a word $w\in\{a^n b^n c^n  \mid n \geq 0\}$ from the rest of $\{a^*b^*c^*\}$ might as well accept it, which sounds contradictory to me.

I guess I need to take advantage of the non-deterministic nature of PDAs but I'm out of ideas. If you could offer some advice I would very much appreciate it.

Comment: Interesting point about it seeming contradictory. Indeed, context-free languages are not closed under taking the complement... so there are lots of examples of non-context-free languages that could be "accepted" in the sense you allude to. I'm not a theorist and, as such, can't really reconcile this, but perhaps someone else can chime in on why this isn't something to worry about?

Comment: Note that this generalizes: the complement of $\{a^n b^n c^n d^n e^n\}$ is a CFG.

Comment: [Similar question](http://cs.stackexchange.com/q/307/98).

Comment: Is not the title of this question wrong? E.g. the complement of $\{a^n b^n c^n | n \geq 0\}$ is not $\{a^*b^*c^* - \{a^n b^n c^n | n \geq 0\}\}$.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

No, this is context-free. To accept $a^nb^nc^n$, you need to make sure that three numbers are equal. To accept $a^*b^*c^* \setminus a^nb^nc^n$, you just need to make sure that you're in one of the following three cases:

1. The number of $a$s is different from the number of $b$s; or
2. The number of $a$s is different from the number of $c$s; or
3. The number of $b$s is different from the number of $c$s.

Write a PDA for each of these cases, then combine them by jumping nondeterministically to each one from the start state.

Comment: I'd written down these cases alright, but I was missing the idea to connect them. Thank you!

Comment: Actually you need only any two cases.

Comment: @sdcvvc Good point. :)

Comment: For different number of characters, consider this as inspiration: $S → xSy | X | Y ; X → x | xX ; Y → y | yY$. It should be simple to glue either $a^+$ onto the left of this or $c^+$ onto the right and turn this into a PDA.  For the tricky case (which you don't need) $S → aSc | A | C ; A →aB | aA ; C → Bc | Cc ; B → ε | bB$.