# Could anyone prove that this is a context free language or not?

Tags: context-free

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Show that $\{xy \mid |x| = |y|, x\neq y\}$ is context-free](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/307/show-that-xy-mid-x-y-x-neq-y-is-context-free)

Can anyone prove that the following is a CFL? or not? why?

$$L=\{w=w_1w_2 \mid len(w_1)=len(w_2) \mbox{ and $w_1$ does not equal $w_2$}\}$$

Comment: What have you tried?  Have you tried making a PDA?  Do you know the pumping lemma for CFLs?

Answer (score 2):

This must be a classic in formal language theory. The Pumping Lemma will not help, because, unexpectedly, it *is* context-free. (I did not see the answer here, but it might be overlooked)

The $w_1$ and $w_2$ parts must have a position where they differ. Unfortunately, we cannot distinguish the middle *and* the two matching positions at the same time. However, we can find matching positions *without* knowing the middle.

With some effort you can convince yourself that your language $L$ equals
$$\{ x_1 a x_2 b x_3 \mid a,b \in \Sigma, a\neq b, |x_1|+|x_3| = |x_2| \}.$$
Once you have shown that, write a grammar using that formulation.

Comment: This is a great idea to convert that language to an equivalent one but could you please explain more? and how did that inspired?! <br>
at last i was not able to say that, this is CFG or not

Comment: Dear @Saman, the question has now been marked as duplicate. At the start of the question you will find a link to the earlier occurrence. It seems to have more detailed suggestions. Have a look.