# Non context free language that is pumpable?

Tags: context-free, pumping-lemma

For my homework assignment, I have to come up with a non-cfl that is pumpable. I came up with the following: 
$$ C = \{a^n b^n c^n d^m \mid n \ge 1 \text{ and } m \ge 1 \} $$

I'm not sure whether this works. For the pumping lemma, let $p$ being the pumping length. If I generate a string with $p$ $a$'s, $b$'s, and $c$'s, and only one $d$, my only choice for $vxy$ would be $d$. Pumping this down to $v^0xy^0$ gives $a^p b^p c^p$, thus escaping the language. However, if I let $m$ be greater than or equal to zero, if I choose a string with no $d$'s, then I am forced to put either $a$'s, $b$'s or $c$'s in my $vxy$ string.

Comment: See [Example of a non-context free language that nonetheless CAN be pumped?](http://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/12041/example-of-a-non-context-free-language-that-nonetheless-can-be-pumped) for some examples.

Comment: I don't get the examples there; they seem a little too complex lol. this is a homework problem, and i have to proof that it's not a cfl by arguing my way through, so i'd like to keep the language simple.

Comment: @YuenHsi: If it's homework, you should do it by yourself.

Comment: @Raphael If that is the spirit of this site, then you should close the question.

Comment: @Raphael So did you get in University of Kaiserslautern and become a PhD student without ever asking for help for any homework assignments?

Comment: @HendrikJan [No, I can't](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/questions/468/homework-policy), all that is covered by policy is [upholding the normal standards](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/questions/594/the-return-of-the-homework-question). Insofar, my above comment is more advice than moderator's note.

Comment: @YuenHsi I don't see how that is relevant here. Note, though, that "asking for help" and "asking for a solution" are different things; your question is somewhere in the middle. Homework is only there to help you understand things (it produces only work for the teachers!) and this is faciliated by *doing the work*, not knowing the answer. Many students misunderstand and fail, angry, "but I looked at all the answers!". So please, no offense intended but only advice.

Answer (score 0):

As you say "thus escaping the language" which means your example language is *not* pumpable: for $m=1$ we cannot pump $d$ and stay in the language. Instead consider $D= C \cup \{a,b,c\}^*$. Now we can pump $d$ whenever it is present, and we can pump any string that does not contain $d$.

Comment: Hey, thanks for your response; I thought of doing that but I didn't know how to proof that D is not context free. Even though C isn't a CFL, I thought CFL languages are not closed under union? {a, b, c}* is regular, isn't it?