# Creating PDA for {xy such that |x|=|y| and x ≠ y}

Tags: formal-languages, pushdown-automata

I'm trying to create a PDA for $\{xy \mid |x|=|y| \text{ and } x \ne y\}$ over the alphabet $\Sigma = \{a, b\}$. But I don't know how the PDA will know if the two strings $x$ and $y$ are not equal. Please help me create this PDA step by step.

Comment: Use nondeterminism. Try to guess the position $i$ where $x$ and $y$ differ. You have to verify your guess. Use the stack to count to position $i$.

Comment: This language *is* context-free! and A.Schultz has a good hint. Do not try to find the middle of the word, just guess position $i$. (I stress this as people are presently trying to prove the contrary in the answers.) The question is more or less a duplicate of [16753](http://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/16753/pushdown-automaton-for-complement-of-l-ww-mid-w-text-in-0-1/) and [307](http://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/307/show-that-xy-mid-x-y-x-neq-y-is-context-free/)