# Looking for a contex-free grammar for the following language

Tags: formal-languages, context-free

I want to derive a context free grammar for the following language on alphabet $\Sigma=\{a,b\}$:

$\qquad\displaystyle \{ xax'yby'z \mid x,y,z\in\Sigma ^*, |x|=|x'|, |y|=|y'|, |z|=|x|+|y|\}$

I am convinced that this language is context-free because this is part of my proof to a theorem given in textbook, but haven't yet seen a context-free grammar for it.

Comment: Look at this old question [Show that {xy∣|x|=|y|,x≠y} is context-free](http://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/307/show-that-xy-mid-x-y-x-neq-y-is-context-free) which is almost the same (except that a,b may swap positions there)

Comment: @HendrikJan It's almost the same only without the $z$ part.

Comment: @YuvalFilmus Yes, can you give any hint about his exercise 2? I don't have enough reputation to comment in that question.

Comment: @YuvalFilmus Sorry, I missed the $z$ part. Now I am curious what "theorem given in textbook" is relevant for this language?

Comment: @HendrikJan Almost the same with exercise given by Raphael in his answer to that old question

Comment: @Raphael About your exercise, the language is the union of three languages. In the case x≠y, a grammar can be constructed just like the old problem. But in the case x≠y (or y≠z), I haven't figured out how to make sure that |z|=|x|+|y|. When considering PDA, we can push 2|x| when reading x, but don't know how to pop exactly |x| when reading x', so still can't see how to deal with z. Thank you for your attention.

Comment: @Raphael I am actually considering proving this not a CFG since $ww^Ra^{|w|}$ can be proved not a CFG by pumping lemma

Comment: @Raphael I got it. The idea is still rearranging the irrelevant letters and try to obtain symmetry.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: you want to measure size of $x$ and $y$, and still have the sum of the two in the end. so when you read them, you will need twice their size: one for $x'$, and one for $z$.
Start with designing a PDA, it seems easier than a grammar.
Then you can use a PDA-to-grammar translation to get the wanted grammar.