# Are these valid counterexamples to proofs for CF languages with Non-CF complements?

Tags: formal-languages, context-free, formal-grammars

Someone asked for [examples of context-free languages with non-context-free complements](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/19266/examples-of-context-free-languages-with-a-non-context-free-complements).

The first answer says:

> The language $L_1= \{ww \mid w \in \{a,b\}^*\}$ is not context-free (as can be shown using the pumping lemma; see [here](https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/19218/755)).  Its complement $L_2 = \{a,b\}^* \setminus L_1$ is context-free (as shown [here](https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/19151/755)).

Maybe in reality this is true, but given the above information, I am not convinced this is a valid example of such a language. I have proved before that $L$ is not CF, so I have no problem accepting that. However, the [CFG and proof](https://cs.stackexchange.com/a/19155/40750) given for $L_2$ are wrong. I can give a really simple counterexample: when the string $s=aaabaa$. Clearly $s \in L_2$ because it's not of the form $ww$. However, $s$ cannot be constructed using the CFG described for $L_2$.

Proof: The string $s$ is not of the form $A$ or $B$ since the length of the string is even. Therefore it must be of the form $AB$ or $BA$, but this is impossible because both halves of the string have the same character ($a$) in the center. Therefore $s \notin L_2$, which is a contradiction.

The second answer says:

> The example you see on Wikipedia: put $A=\{a^n b^n c^m\}$, $B=\{a^m b^n c^n\}$. It's easy to see $\overline{A}$ and $\overline{B}$ are context-free by defining a PDA; you can note that they're deterministic context-free languages, which is a class closed under complement. Therefore $\overline{A} \cup \overline{B}$ is a context-free language with a non-contextfree complement $A \cap B=\{a^n b^n c^n\}$.

This one is even easier to disprove. Sure, deterministic context-free languages are closed under complement, but they're *not* closed under union. Therefore, the language $\overline{A} \cup \overline{B}$ is not necessarily context free.

I am currently still taking Theory of Computing, so perhaps I've gotten something wrong or overlooked some obvious truth. Can anyone disprove my claims? If not, can you provide a valid example of a CF language with a non-CF complement?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For the first question, $aaabaa$ is generated by the grammar:
$$\begin{align*}
    S&\to AB \\
     &\to aB &&\text{using }A\to a\\
     &\to aaBa &&\text{using }B\to aBa\\
     &\to aaaBaa &&\text{using }B\to aBa\\
     &\to aaabaa &&\text{using }B\to b\,.
\end{align*}$$
Your attempt to prove the converse is incorrect because you assume that, when the string is split as $AB$, the part generated by $A$ must have the same length as the part generated by $B$. As the derivation above shows, this is not true.

For the second, you're correct that the class of deterministic CFLs is not closed under union. However, the class of CFLs *is* closed under union. That is, the union of two DCFLs is not necessarily a DCFL but it is definitely a CFL. The argument "$\overline{A}$ and $\overline{B}$ are deterministic context-free, so they are context-free, so $\overline{A}\cup\overline{B}$ is context-free" is implicit in the proof you quote.