# There exists an algorithm to find grammar of complement of a function?

Tags: formal-languages, formal-grammars

I'm wondering if there exists an algorithm to solve the following problem:

> Given a grammar $S$ of a context-free language $\mathcal{L}$, find a grammar
>   $S'$ such as $L(S) = L(S')^c $.

I note that the complement of a context-free language is also a context-free language, so the questions is well stated.

Answer (score 6):

Contrary to what you wrote, context-free languages are [not closed under complement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Context-free_language#Nonclosure_under_intersection,_complement,_and_difference).  See [Examples of context-free languages with a non-context-free complements](https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/19266/755) for some examples.  As a result, there is no such algorithm.

Also: It's decidable whether $L(S)=\emptyset$, but it's not decidable whether $L(S)=\Sigma^*$.  If you could compute the complement, then you could decide the latter using the algorithm for the former.

In contrast, deterministic context-free languages *are* [closed under complement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deterministic_context-free_language#Properties), and the proof of that fact likely identifies an algorithm that will work when you have a deterministic context-free language.  Another way to handle it: convert to a deterministic pushdown automaton, then it is clear how to complement it.

Comment: Okay, I'm speachless now because I've been taught they were closed under complement, did't know they were talking about the deterministic context-free languages (didn't even know such thing existed).

· Do you recommend any book where to find that proof?
· Given a pushdown automaton how can I get the grammar by an algorithmic way? (I don't know if it's okay to ask this here or should I ask it in a different post). Sorry, I'm a newbie here.

Comment: @JayJay, I learned from Hopcroft, Motwani, and Ullman.  I haven't verified that it has that proof, but I'd guess it's a good bet it will.  Other people have had good things to say about Sipser's book (Introduction to Theory of Computation).

Answer (score 1):

Since you didn't explicitly specify that $S'$ should be a *context-free* grammar, I'll take the opportunity to mention [Boolean grammars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boolean_grammar), which are a fairly modest extension of CFGs that allow conjunction and negation in rules, in addition to the implicit disjunction of CFGs. The productions have the form

> $$A \to \alpha_1 \And \ldots \And \alpha_m \And
> \lnot\beta_1 \And \ldots \And \lnot\beta_n$$
>   where $A$ is a nonterminal, $m+n \ge 1$ and $\alpha_1$, ..., $\alpha_m$, $\beta_1, \ldots, \beta_n$ are strings formed of symbols in $\Sigma$ and $N$. Informally, such a rule asserts that every string $w$ over $\Sigma$ that satisfies each of the syntactical conditions represented by $\alpha_1$, ..., $\alpha_m$ and none of the syntactical conditions represented by $\beta_1$, ..., $\beta_n$ therefore satisfies the condition defined by $A$.

Then if $G$ is a Boolean grammar (in particular, it could be a CFG) with start symbol $S$, add a new start symbol $S'$ and add the rule $S' \rightarrow \lnot S$ to obtain a grammar for $L(G)^c$.

Boolean grammars are a "modest" extension in that the deterministic time complexity of parsing is the same as for CFGs and they can be defined by language equations, but on the other hand they recognize a much larger class of languages. For example, even conjunctive grammars do not satisfy Parikh's theorem (i.e., the conjunctive grammars over an unary alphabet recognize non-regular languages). It is an open problem whether conjunctive grammars are closed under complementation.