# Is the difference of two context-free languages still context-free?

Tags: formal-languages, context-free, closure-properties

i am asking myself the following question:

Assuming: **A** and **B** are context-free languages, then **A - B** (difference) must also be context-free language, right?
but I do not know how to prove it.

Answer (score 7):

The complement of a context-free language $L$ is not necessarily context-free, but it is the difference between two context-free languages ($\Sigma^* - L$). (Here $\Sigma$ is the alphabet of $L$.)

See, for example, [Is the complement of { ww | ... } context-free?](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/19151/is-the-complement-of-ww-context-free) for an example of a context-free language whose complement is not context-free.

Answer (score 2):

It might be context sensitive as well...

example:-

let

> L1= ${\{a^n b^n c^m | n>0, m>0\}}$

and

> L2=${\{a^m b^n c^n | m>0, n>0\}}$

Here L1 and L2 are context free but L1-L2 will be

> L1-L2 = ${\{a^n b^n c^m | n>0, m>0 \space \& \space n \neq m\}}$

which is NOT context free.