# A context free grammar for the language of even-length non-palindromes

Tags: formal-languages, context-free, formal-grammars

I am trying to find a context free grammar for the language

> $L = \{xy \mid |x|=|y| \text{ and } x≠y^R\}$

where $y^R$ is the reverse of string y and $x, y\in \{a,b\}^*$ . Here is a possible solution:
$G=\{V,Σ,R,S\}$
where
$V=\{A,B,a,b\}$
$Σ=\{a,b\}$
$R=\{S\rightarrow aSa|bSb|aBb|bBa,$
   $\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ B\rightarrow aBa|bBb|aBb|bBa\}$

Is this correct?

I found a similar problem [here](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/307/show-that-xy-mid-x-y-x-neq-y-is-context-free).

Comment: Try to prove that it's correct.

Comment: Your question already includes a complete answer to the original problem but no question *about* this answer. Thus, only "yes/no" answers may remain, helping neither you nor future visitors. Please read related meta discussions [here](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/questions/597/) and [here](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/questions/519/) and adjust your question accordingly, e.g. by formulating a specific question about a single element of your answer you are uncertain about. If you just want general feedback, you are welcome to visit us in [chat].