# Context-free grammar for all words not of the form w#w

Tags: context-free, formal-grammars

I was asked to define a CFG for the complement of $\{w\#w \mid w \in \{0,1\}^*\}$ and I'm struggling to define it. I think it is quite similar to defining a CFG for the complement of $\{ww \mid w \in \{0,1\}^*\}$, but  I'm finding that the '#' really messes things up. Is the language even context-free?

Comment: Have you tried *proving* that your language is not context-free?

Comment: How can I define the language to do so?

Comment: See also [How can ws with |w| = |s| and w ≠ s be context-free while w#s is not?](https://cs.stackexchange.com/a/74726/4287) for similar languages, and an example where the difference between (non-)context-freeness can be tricky.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If a word is *not* of the form $w\#w$ then one of the following must happen:

- It contains no $\#$.
- It contains more than one $\#$.
- It is of the form $x\#y$, where $x,y \in \{0,1\}^*$ and $x \neq y$, in which case one of the following must happen:

  - $|x| > |y|$ or $|x| < |y|$.
  - $x_i = 0$ and $y_i = 1$ for some $i$, or vice versa.

The only case which is non-trivial to handle is the last one, in which case we have a word of the form
$$
x_1 0 x_2 \# y_1 1 y_2,
$$
where $|x_1| = |y_1|$. We can split this into
$$
x_1 \;\; 0x_2\# \;\; y_1 \;\; 1y_2,
$$
where $|x_1| = |y_1|$. This should make it clear how to construct a CFG for such words.

---

Altogether, we obtain the following grammar:
\begin{align}
&S \to A \mid B \mid C \mid D \mid E \mid F \\
&A \to 0A \mid 1A \mid \epsilon \\
&B \to A\#B \mid A\#A\#A \\
&C \to A0G \mid A1G \\
&D \to G0A \mid G1A \\
&G \to 0G0 \mid 0G1 \mid 1G0 \mid 1G1 \mid \# \\
&E \to E_11A \\
&E_1 \to 0E_10 \mid 0E_11 \mid 1E_10 \mid 1E_11 \mid 0A\# \\
&F \to F_10A \\ 
&F_1 \to 0F_10 \mid 0F_11 \mid 1F_10 \mid 1F_11 \mid 1A\# \\
\end{align}

In this grammar:

- $A$ generates words without $\#$
- $B$ generates words with more than one $\#$
- $C$ generates words of the form $x\#y$ with $|x| > |y|$
- $D$ generates words of the form $x\#y$ with $|x| < |y|$
- $E$ generates words of the form $x_10x_2\#y_11y_2$ with $|x_1|=|y_1|$
- $F$ generates words of the form $x_11x_2\#y_10y_2$ with $|x_1|=|y_1|$
- $G$ generates words of the form $x\#y$ with $|x| = |y|$

Comment: I've been trying to test it and it seems correct, thank you very much! I was having a hard time with this one!