# Find PDA for CFL = {x#y | |x| = |y| and x ≠ y}

Tags: formal-languages, context-free, pushdown-automata

I am studying push down automata.

When I read a solution for showing $L = \{x\#y \mid x \neq y, x,y \in \{0,1\}^*\}$ is a CFL, I could understand $L = L_1 \cup L_2$, $L_1 = \{x\#y\mid|x| \neq |y|\}$, $L_2 = \{x\#y \mid|x| = |y|,x \neq y\}$, and make a CFG for $L_1$, but I don't know how to make a CFG for $L_2$, since $y$ is not a reverse string of $x$. How can I know the $i_\text{th}$ symbol is different?

Note this question is different from [Show that { xy ∣ |x| = |y|, x ≠ y } is context-free](https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/307/83244) since we have an additional separator $\#$.

Comment: how to know where # is?

Comment: This is a rare confusing case. The right answer is that $\{x\#y \mid|x| = |y|,x \neq y\}$ is NOT context-free. Please see [How can    with  ||=||  and  ≠  be context-free while  #  is not?](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/74701/how-can-ws-with-w-s-and-w-%E2%89%A0-s-be-context-free-while-w-s-is-not/74726#74726) or [_find a pushdown automaton for { x#y ∣ x ≠ y }_](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/42287/find-a-pushdown-automaton-for-xy-%E2%88%A3-x-%E2%89%A0-y).

Comment: @MrDrinkSoju I have changed the duplicate to point to a question that I think answer the question for the right language.