# Is the concatenation of a non-regular CFL and a complement of a regular upper-set always non-regular?

Tags: regular-languages, context-free

Let $L_1$ be a non-regular CFL. Let $L_2$ be a regular language. Assume that $\left(L_1\right)^{*} \subseteq L_2$. I'm looking at $L_3 = \left( L_1 \right) ^{*} \circ \overline{L_2}$. Is $L_3$ always non-regular? I can find multiple examples of it being non-regular, yet none of it being regular.

Edit: $\overline{L_2} \neq \emptyset$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider the language $L = \{uv\mid u, v\in\Sigma^*, |u|=|v|\wedge u\neq v\}$. I claim that $L$ is [context-free](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/307/show-that-xy-%E2%88%A3-x-y-x-%E2%89%A0-y-is-context-free), it is not regular (a simple pumping lemma proof can do the trick), but $L^*$ is regular, without being equal to $\Sigma^*$, so that means that $L^*\overline{L^*}$ is regular and satisfies your conditions.

Now let's show that if we denote $L'= (\Sigma\Sigma)^*\setminus\left(\bigcup\limits_{a\in\Sigma}a^*\right)\cup \{\varepsilon\}$ (words of even length, not composed of the same letter), then $L^*=L'$:

- the inclusion $\subseteq$ is the easiest, since words of $L$ are of even length, and are not composed of the same letter. We added $\varepsilon$ to $L'$ by definition of the Kleene star;
- let's prove by induction that $L'\subseteq L^*$:

  - consider $w\in L'$; if $w = \varepsilon$, then $w\in L^*$, if $|w| = 2$, then $w\in L$ (because it contains two different letters), so $w\in L^*$;
  - suppose the result proved for words of length up to a certain $2n\in\mathbb{N}$, and consider $w\in L'$ of length $2n+2$. If $w\in L$, then trivially, $w\in L^*$. Otherwise, since $|w|$ is even, then $w = uu$, with $u\in\Sigma^*$, $u$ containing different letters.

    - If $|u|$ is even, then it means that $u \in L'$
    - Otherwise, $u = u_1u_2…u_{2k+1}$, and we can show that $uu = xy$ verifying $x,y\in L'$ (with either $x = u_1…u_{2k}$ and $y = u_{2k+1}u$ or $x=uu_1$ and $y = u_2…u_{2k+1}$).

    In all cases, we can use the induction hypothesis to show that $w\in L^*$.

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit more on why $L^{*}$ is regular? I can see its an upper-set of $\left\{ \left( a b \right) ^{*} \right\}$, but it also contains other forms of strings...

Comment: The language $L' = (\Sigma\Sigma)^*\setminus\left(\bigcup\limits_{a\in\Sigma}a^*\right)\cup \{\varepsilon\}$ is regular because $(\Sigma\Sigma)^*$ regular, and so are $a^*$ for $a\in\Sigma$ and $\{\varepsilon\}$. If we use [closure properties](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_language#Closure_properties) of regular languages, then it shows that $L'$ is regular. $L^*$ is regular because I proved it equal to $L'$.

Comment: I see that now. But, are you assuming $\left| \Sigma \right| = 1$ ?  If not (assuming for example that $\left| \Sigma \right| = 2$) then $L^{'} $ should exclude $\left\{ b^{*} \right\}$ as well, right?

Comment: I am not assuming $|\Sigma| = 1$ otherwise $L$ would be empty, that's why I wrote $\bigcup\limits_{a\in\Sigma} a^*$, to exclude all words composed of the same letter, whatever the letter is. Here, the notation $a$ is a free variable.