# Is this language a context-free language or not?

Tags: formal-languages, context-free, pumping-lemma

I try to determine if the following statement is true:

for any given language $L \subseteq A^*$ if $L$ is a context-free language then $L_1 = \{u^Rv^R \ | \ uv \in L, |u|=|v| \}$ is also a context-free language.

Initially I tried to come up with a counterexample but now I start to believe this statement could be true. As far as I know I could prove that language is not a context-free language using pumping lemma but how can I prove this language is a context-free one (if it's true)? I would be grateful for any hints.

Edit: I found interesting and maybe related question: [Show that { xy ∣ |x| = |y|, x ≠ y } is context-free](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/307/show-that-xy-%e2%88%a3-x-y-x-%e2%89%a0-y-is-context-free)

Based on the question from the above link I started to wonder if language $L = \{uv \ | \ |u|=|v| \}$ is a context-free language only if $u \neq v$. If it's true then answer to my question is obvious.

Comment: Consider  $L_2=\{vu \ | \ uv \in L, |u|=|v| \}$. Since $L_2=L_1^R$, $L_1$ is context-free iff $L_2$ is context-free. So the statement in the question is the same as "$L$ is context-free iff $L_2$ is context-free", assuming all words in $L$ are of even length.  ($L=(L_2)_2$.)

Comment: @JohnL. Interesting observation. I would bet that your $L_2 = \{ vu \mid uv\in L, |u|=|v| \}$ is the topic of an old question here, but cannot find it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No, $L_1$ is not necessarily context-free.

---

For example, let $L=\{0^n1^{3n}\mid n\ge0\}$.

If $ uv=0^n1^{3n}$ and $|u|=|v|$, then $u=0^n1^n$ and $v=1^{2n}$. We have $u^Rv^R=1^n0^n1^{2n}$.

So, $L_1=\{1^n0^n1^{2n}\mid n\ge0\}$, which is not context-free.

Comment: Conjecture: If all words in $L$ are of even length and both $L$ and $L_1$ are context-free, then both of them are regular.

Comment: Regarding your comment's conjecture: $a^mb^nc^nd^m$.

Answer (score 3):

I do not think the linked question is relevant.

Consider the context-free language $L = \{a^n b^n c^m d^m \mid m,n\ge 0\}$.

Let us consider an example string, $uv = a^3 b^3 c^8 d^8 $.
Assuming $u$ and $v$ are of equal length,
$u= a^3 b^3 c^5$ and $v= c^3 d^8 $. Thus $u^Rv^R = c^5 b^3 a^3 d^8 c^3$.
We see that the letters are in a rather scrambled order.

Now study the minimally scrambled strings in the new language, meaning $L_1 \cap b^* a^* d^* c^*$.

What is that language?

Comment: I was like "what the heck is this?" when I wrote my wrong answer. Now I see this answer is also simple and correct.

Comment: @JohnL. Thanks. Of course your final solution is a "deserved winner".